# How to install Ubuntu on HTC one x

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to install Ubuntu on my htc one x. please help me in this regard.

I have a problem when I run this command:

```
sudo fastboot oem ublock
```

Comment: What error message do you get if any.  Also where did you get that command from - If you are following an online guide add a link to it.

Comment: He is probably trying "phablet-flash" since that has the instruction above. But that only works for a Nexus.  See here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/endeavoru Currently there is no 100% installable Ubuntu for the HTC one x.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

Not <strike>ublock</strike>, notice that you shouldn't need to use `sudo` unless you are missing proper `udev` rules.

From then on you would need to push the update zips corresponding to the target platform.